# How can I force a column to be unique for an entire table in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, primary-key, unique

I have a table with a `Description` field.  I want to ensure that no two rows have the same "Description," but I can't make Description into my identity column (my ID column is an int).

Is it safe to set `Description` as a second primary key (in addition to my ID which is already a primary key)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a Unique index to the Description column.

Using Sql Server Management Studio right click on the table and choose Design. Then right click on a column and choose "Indexes/keys". You will be prompted with the following window

[image]

Click on Add on the bottom left and then specify properties for your index. If you want to use a DDL script then use something like this

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_INDEXNAME] ON [dbo].[TABLENAME] 
(
    [Description] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: I suggest using a uniqueness constraint instead of an index. The constraint syntax is the more conventional way to implement key constraints. Unlike the index syntax, constraints are standard SQL and are more likely to be understood and recognised by other users of the database and by software tools that access db schema metadata. A uniqueness constraint automatically creates an index for you.

Comment: I also suggest that you should always do this (and any other DDL changes) in the script, so they can be properly versioned and stored in your soruce control system. Database changes should never be made from the Management Studio GUI.

Comment: When I try to "Add" an item and click on Columns under (General) it only gives me the option to select my "id" column and doesn't let me (or even display) the "String" column in the drop-down combo box. I only have two columns, one is an id, the other just a text column where every item should be unique.

Why won't it allow me to select the text-based column under the indexes/keys section when i click add and go to column?

Answer (score 29):

There is no such thing as a 'secondary primary key'. There is one primary key per table.

Create a [UNIQUE constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx) on the `Description` column (highly unusual thing to do, BTW. For example, It is more usual to create a unique index on `Product Name` rather than a `Product description`) or if you have null values in the `Description` column create a [Filtered index](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) (SQL Server 2008 onwards)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.yourTable
   ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_yourTable_Description UNIQUE ([Description]);
```

Comment: This should be the Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do this with the SSMS GUI if you prefer:

I've replaced the `Description` column with the name `MyUniqueColumn` for the sake of the example.

1. Right click "Indexes" under your table in the SSMS Solution Explorer and click "New Index..." (I know you are looking to create a contstraint, not an index, but this is exactly what the `ADD CONSTRAINT` SQL script does.

[image]

2. Give new index a name (e.g. "UQ_MyUniqueColumn"), check "Unique", and click "Add..."

[image]

3. Check your column in the next window

[image]

4. Click OK in both windows

Comment: I cannot view images (my firewall company blocks). Is possible ***transcript text in images to text (SQL)*** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet The images are just screen shots of the numbered steps. Let me know if you can't follow any of the steps and I will add more text.

Comment: Nice detailed answer that explains well what is actually happening.